# Bind generic type (scanning) to concrete instance with generic method call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, structuremap

Using StructureMap I want to bind `IQueryable<T>` to `ApplicationDbContext.Set<T>().AsQueryable()`.

So I can inject like this.

```
public class Foo
{
  public Foo(IQueryable<MyEntity> query)
  {
  }
}
```

I've gotten this far

```
config.For(typeof(IQueryable<>))
  .Use(x => 
    x.GetInstance<ApplicationDbContext>().Set<TNotWorking>().AsQueryable());
```

But I can't figure out how to get the `TNotWorking` working :) I guess reflection isn't an option here, also I would avoid it if possible.

Comment: You can't do it w/o reflection w/o knowing the concrete type **at compile time**, because `Set<T>` requires T to be know at compile time and it has no overload for `Set(typeof(T))`. Why not just write an abstract class for your dbcontext and a single `.Set<T>` method? Also your design as a few flaws. When having more than a single context, you can't know from which one it comes w/o creating an implementation for each entity as its own queryiable

Comment: I think the most important part is "why do you inject `IQueryable<Entity>`?" which looks like an incorrect design!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it's not possible w/o reflection or implementing each entity as a type in your project.

The last approach could look like this. When you create a base class which implements `IQueryable<T>`, then the code required for adding new entities is minimal and will also work when there is more than a single `DbContext` available for injection, which is almost always the case in any non-trivial demo application.

```
public abstract class QueryableEntityBase<TEntity> : IQueryable<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    protected QueryableEntityBase(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        Queryable = context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    }

    public Type ElementType => Queryable.ElementType;

    public Expression Expression => Queryable.Expression;

    public IQueryProvider Provider => Queryable.Provider;
    protected IQueryable<TEntity> Queryable { get; }
    private DbContext Context { get; }

    public IEnumerator<TEntity> GetEnumerator() => Queryable.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => Queryable.GetEnumerator();
}

// You need to create this per entity you want to be injectable
public class MyQueryableEntity : QueryableEntityBase<MyEntity>
{
    public MyQueryableEntity(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context) { }
}
```

This has the additional advantage that you can change the underlying query/persistence provider by entity, by changing `QueryableEntityBase<T>` base with `MonogoDbQueryableEntityBase<T>` which uses an `IMongoClient` instead of `DbContext`.

The registration should be something along the line of (not familiar with StructureMap, you'd need to register all of it's types though or scan the assembly).

```
config.For(typeof(IQueryable<>)).Use(typeof(QueryableEntityBase<>));
```

In a simple case where you only have a single database, you could also make the base class non-abstract and just resolve `QueryableEntity<T>`, but like I said you'll hit the limitation of one single DbContext per app sooner or later, so it's best to be done explicitly.

Or alternatively extend the implementation so you can define the context too

```
public class QueryableEntityBase<TContext, TEntity> : IContextSetQueryable<TDbContext, TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity> where TEntity : class, TContext : DbContext
{
    private TContext Context { get; }

    protected QueryableEntityBase(TContext context)
    {
        Context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        Queryable = context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

But then you need an additional interface:

```
public interface IContextSetQueryable<TContext, TContext> : IQueryable<TEntity> where TContext : DbContext { }
```

Then inject `IContextSetQueryable<TContext, TContext> entity` into your services.

But then you lose the ability to have persistence agnostic domain, since you'll need the ability to reference `DbContext` and it's subtypes, so it's not really elegant and you could as well use database specific interfaces, such as

```
public interface ISomethingDatabase
{
    IQueryable<User> Users { get; }
    IQueryable<Customer> Customers { get; }
    ...
}
```